# How to insert data from a dict in the Entry tkinter widgets

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry

I need a matrix of Entry widgets with pre-defined values inserted. It works when explicitly typing a string or int the value is shown in widget. However, when referencing a dictionary the output is .!labelframe3.!entry instead.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Simulador de Proteção")
root.iconbitmap("logo.ico")
root.geometry("1200x800")
root.configure(background='black')


# FRAME DA CAIXA DE TESTE

# gerar lista de sinais
signals_list = ['IA', 'IB', 'IC']
initial_values = {'mag-pre':0, 'phi-pre':120, 'mag-fault':0, 'phi-fault':0, 'mag-pos':0, 'phi-pos':0}
signals_entries = dict.fromkeys(signals_list, initial_values)
signals_values = dict.fromkeys(signals_list, initial_values)
columns_list = list(initial_values.keys())

# criar o frame
frame_testbox = LabelFrame(root, text="Caixa de teste")
frame_testbox.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

# mostrar nomes das linhas
row_idx = 1
for signal in signals_list:
    label = Label(frame_testbox, text=signal)
    label.grid(row=row_idx, column=0)
    row_idx += 1

# mostrar nomes das colunas
label = Label(frame_testbox, text="Sinal")
label.grid(row=0, column=0)
col_idx = 1
for col in columns_list:
    label = Label(frame_testbox, text=col)
    label.grid(row=0, column=col_idx)
    col_idx += 1

# criar campos de entrada
row_idx = 0
for signal in signals_list:
    row_idx += 1
    col_idx = 1
    for col in columns_list:
        signals_entries[signal][col] = Entry( frame_testbox, width=15, bg="white", fg="black", borderwidth=5 )
        signals_entries[signal][col].grid(row=row_idx, column=col_idx)
        signals_entries[signal][col].insert(0, signals_values[signal][col] )
        col_idx += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the following code to show the *id* for the values of `signals_entries` and `signals_values`:

```py
signals_entries = dict.fromkeys(signals_list, initial_values)
signals_values = dict.fromkeys(signals_list, initial_values)

for col in signals_entries:
    print(f"entries:{col}: {id(signals_entries[col])}")
    print(f"values :{col}: {id(signals_values[col])}")
```

you will get the following result:

```
entries:IA: 2141266080512
values :IA: 2141266080512
entries:IB: 2141266080512
values :IB: 2141266080512
entries:IC: 2141266080512
values :IC: 2141266080512
```

The result shows that all values of `signals_entries` and `signals_values` are referencing the same dictionary.

So the following line in the last `for` loop:

```py
signals_entries[signal][col] = Entry( frame_testbox, width=15, bg="white", fg="black", borderwidth=5 )
```

will change the values of that dictionary to entry widgets.

Therefore `signals_values[signal][col]` (referencing the same dictionary) will be the entry widget as well.

You need to change the following two lines:

```py
signals_entries = dict.fromkeys(signals_list, initial_values)
signals_values = dict.fromkeys(signals_list, initial_values)
```

to

```py
signals_entries = {col:initial_values.copy() for col in signals_list}
signals_values = {col:initial_values.copy() for col in signals_list}
```

And the result:

[image]